# Google closure compiler ant task locks files after completion? Release lock on complete

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, minify, google-closure-compiler

I'm running an ant script that uses the google's closure compiler (https://github.com/google/closure-compiler) ant task (application downloaded from here, https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/), the compiler modifies the files correctly minified **but closure compiler fails to release lock after the script completes.** I thought this was a bug and posted the issue on the github repo, as running other commands over the fileset does not cause any problems until I added the closure-compiler command However I'm not sure anymore, I'm new to ant buildscripts and was wondering if someone can help me out. Is there a work around?

Note:
The file locks remaining is causing problems as I am unable to delete files in another script.
The file lock is only released when I close eclipse.
Am I doing something wrong? as the file locks are not released after the script completes.
Is this an issue with eclipse? I've been pulling out my hair trying to figure this out.
I'm running this on windows and within eclipse neon.

Below is my ant buildscript to reproduce the issue:

```
    <property name="root-folder" value="C:/workspaceprojects" />
<property name="lib-folder" value="${root-folder}/resource/lib"/>
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties" classpath="${lib-folder}/ant/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar"/>
<taskdef name="xmltask" classname="com.oopsconsultancy.xmltask.ant.XmlTask" classpath="${lib-folder}/ant/xmltask.jar"/>

<taskdef name="closure-compiler" classname="com.google.javascript.jscomp.ant.CompileTask"
    classpath="${lib-folder}/closure-compiler/closure-compiler.jar"/>

<!--main loop-->    
<target name="main">
    <foreach target="minify-js" param="filepath">
        <path>
            <fileset dir="C:\Users\phoang\Documents/supports-color" casesensitive="yes">
                <include name="**/*.js"/>
            </fileset>
        </path>
    </foreach>
</target>

<!-- Google Closure Compiler -->
<target name="minify-js">
        <sequential>

        <echo message="Compressing file ${filepath}" />

        <propertyregex property="jsfilename" override="true" input="${filepath}" regexp=".*\\(.*\.js)" select="\1" /> 
        <propertyregex property="jsdirpath" override="true" input="${filepath}" regexp="(.*)\\.*\.js" select="\1" />  

        <echo message="${jsfilename}"/>
        <echo message="${jsdirpath}"/>

        <closure-compiler compilationLevel="simple" debug="false" output="${filepath}" forceRecompile="true">
            <sources dir="${jsdirpath}">
                <file name="${jsfilename}"/>
            </sources>
        </closure-compiler>
        </sequential>
</target>
```

Thanks for taking the time to read this.

Comment: Ant task source files: https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/tree/master/src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/ant

Comment: Looking at the source code it seems that its most likely that the file is not being closed properly after writing to it. Unfortunately downloading the entire source code and running the closure compiler might not be an option. Is there any means to flush out or close files that are being read by eclipse through ant?